# How to remember (save in cookie) action from user for a day?

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I have created some web-interface. And have created a little preload feature (pre-saver) for it, before logging in interface.
Trouble is when user came to this interface he must see pre-saver every time - that's annoying. How to do the pre-saver appear one time in a day?
As I understand I must use cookie for that, save some parameter in it? Can I do it via jQuery, or I must use php?
I had never worked with cookie before, need your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `PHP` for 1 day

```
setcookie("TestCookie",$value, time()+3600*24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two readymade function to set cookie by javascript. Be careful! Cookie needs server to work. Use localStorage instead. Here is the link: [javascript cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Ok guys, thank you for your help. I found a concise resource, but in russian:
http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/4
It is more easy than seems before..

Comment: @StasUshakov ok. then that make your work to go. I would also follow the easy path

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thank you for your help. I found a concise resource, but in russian: [codeharmony.ru/materials/4](http://codeharmony.ru/materials/4)

It is more easy than seems before..